# How to retrieve login/password from its Observable? (LoginButton via RxJava)

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to make logining form using Rx in every place I can with MVP architecture. This is how my IView looks like:

```
public interface LoginView_MVP_RX extends LoginView {
    Observable<CharSequence> getLoginObservable();
    Observable<CharSequence> getPasswordObservable();
    Observable<Void> getSignInButtonObservable();
}
```

It works good then I try to enable/disable login button depending on Login+Password EditTexts validations.
But when I'm trying to use `signInButtonObservable()` to login - observables come pain:

```
getView().getSignInButtonObservable()
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .map(v -> {
        String login = getView().getLoginObservable()
            .toBlocking().mostRecent("").iterator().next().toString();
        String password = getView().getPasswordObservable()
            .toBlocking().mostRecent("").iterator().next().toString();
        return authService.signIn(login, password); // long enough
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(user -> getView().setSignedInState(user));
```

And there I got stuck. I'm using [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) for getting `RxView.clicks()` and `RxWidget.onTextChanges()` so its subs must be called on the main thread, so I must call `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before every `toBlocking()`. **But if I do so, it becames async (I guess)! It returns empty login/password (but of course they aren't empty because button enables only then validation passed).**

**Question:**
So the question is: how can I retrieve `mostRecent(String)` synchronously or is there any other way to do this?

---

I found out, there is operator [withLatestFrom()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#withLatestFrom%28rx.Observable,%20rx.functions.Func2%29). But seems like it's in beta support and can be removed. With it, code looks like:

```
getView().getSignInButtonObservable()
    .withLatestFrom(
        Observable.combineLatest(
            getView().getLoginObservable(),
            getView().getPasswordObservable(),
            (login, password) -> new Pair<>(login.toString(), password.toString())),
        (v, loginWithPassword) -> loginWithPassword)
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .map(loginWithPassword -> {
        String login = ((Pair<String, String>)loginWithPassword).first;
        String password= ((Pair<String, String>)loginWithPassword).second;
        return authService.signIn(login, password); // long enough
    }) 
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(user -> getView().setSignedInState(user));
```

Comment: `Observable.combineLatest()` is not experimental and is often used when working with forms, and your second example is generally valid.

Comment: in Rx, if you are using `toBlocking` anywhere else but in tests, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't really understand why you insist on having the login and password return observables, since you don't really care about events on those, but just about getting the value instantly when the click event of the button is fired.

Comment: all this `getView().getLoginObservable()
            .toBlocking().mostRecent("").iterator().next().toString()` looks like it should be replaced with a simple `((TextView getView().findViewById(R.id.login)).getText().toString();` or something

Comment: my understanding here is that your login and password observables are used to trigger the validation of the fields and enable the submit button, right?

Comment: @AndroidEx, I'm talking about `withLatestFrom()`, not `combineLatest()`. Link routs to description of the both of them

Comment: @njzk2, I'm trying to use only RxJava in my MVP (so, no `getView().findViewById()` permissible). I want to do so because if it can be used that way, than it will have really neat design for me. So, the question not **I can't retrieve text from EditText** but **I wanna use RxJava to retrieve(or somehow else) login/pass to send in to authService**

Comment: @Nexen I know what operator you mentioned but in your example you used another one which is 1) not experimental, 2) should be fine for your purposes. At the bottom of [this page](https://medium.com/swlh/party-tricks-with-rxjava-rxandroid-retrolambda-1b06ed7cd29c#.rrurbystq) there is an example called "Login form (RxBinding)", please have a look at it.

Comment: @Nexen where did you see that `withLatestFrom` is in beta?

Comment: you probably don't need `(v, loginWithPassword) -> loginWithPassword)`, you can certainly replace it with the lambda from your `map`

Comment: @AndroidEx, I use such code for my SignInButton too and it works well. But here is another task.

Comment: @njzk2, updated link to `withLatestFrom()` (managed to create its link :/ really bad format..). ` In the `map()` some time-consumable code persists, so I can't replace it as it is. Slightly changed code to clarify this moment.

Comment: @Nexen right, I didn't see the `@Experimental` annotation. But the function is documented in marbles, and implemented in other languages as well, so I would be confident that it should stay.

Comment: @Nexen what you can do, though, is flatMap from `getSignInButtonObservable` to a combineLatest of login and password that would in turn map to your service.

Answer (score 0):

This could work. Not sure about the `subscribeOn` and the `observeOn` as I don't know what thread your observable initially work on:

```
getView().getSignInButtonObservable()
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .flatMap(v -> 
        Observable.combineLatest(
            // BTW, you could simplify that by having getLoginObservable be an Observable<String>
            getView().getLoginObservable().map(CharSequence::toString),
            getView().getPasswordObservable().map(CharSequence::toString),
            Pair::new)).first()
    .map(pair -> authService.signIn(pair.first, pair.second))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(user -> getView().setSignedInState(user));
```

#### Edit

Added `first` to unsubscribe immediatly. `combineLastest` now only returns the first elements pair, which is the text of the TextView

Comment: seems like it will trigger `subscribe()` for every login or pass changes (e.g., I edited login 3 times & pass 5 times. After clicking on button, it will trigger 15 times). But I'm not certain. I will try it later

Comment: @Nexen possible. I may be misusing `combineLatest`. Also, I am not sure whether your login and password observables are hot or cold observables. If cold, `combineLatest` should trigger a subscribe that should get the latest event?

Comment: @Nexen, just checked, and TextViewTextOnSubscribe does fire an initial event whenever you subscribe to it: `subscriber.onNext(view.getText());`. But yeah, having `combineLatest` called each time you get an event from the button would not work, unless you use `first` on it, so it stops immediatly after.

Comment: yeah, my `getLoginObservable()` is hot. It is created by `RxBinding`. And inital event exists too. But it is useless to use `first`, because if I type something in the form after loading `View`, `Observable` will stay silent :(

Comment: @Nexen I don't think so. It looks like a new subscription is created during each event in the flatmap, which should trigger the initial event, which gets the text every time, because that lambda is executed for each onNext event of the button.